# How can I set my very own JSON key label in Django REST API framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use REST API framework in Django and I noticed that the JSON format for it always takes the particular model's field name as the key. eg: A field called image in my model stores images in the database. When viewed in JSON format, it's seen as : **{"image": "apple.png"}**

I want to change the image to my own personalized label. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a serializer with your custom label name and then use custom attribute to instruct drf to use `image` field data.

Something like

```
custom_label = serializers.TextField(source="image")
```

Comment: It's your model field/attribute name.